# What is the proper way to monitor and control a device with delayed feedback?

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I'm having trouble controlling the position of a real-world device using a UISlider. The device accepts directional commands (retract or extend) but not a command for an absolute position. It reports its current position when queried.

For example, if the device is at position 50 and I set the desired position with a UISlider to 25, the program commands the device to head in the direction towards 25. It may take several seconds so I repeatedly query it, and once it reaches 25 I command the device to stop. My current (untested) code looks like this:

```
    func sliderMoved(_ label : UILabel, openCharacteristicNum : Int, closeCharacteristicNum : Int, sender: UISlider){
        let actuatorPosition = getActuatorPosition(label)

        // run this on a background thread
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            if (actuatorPosition > sender.value) {
                // stop closing and start opening
                self.writeValue(closeCharacteristicNum, value: 1)
                self.writeValue(openCharacteristicNum, value: 0)
                while actuatorPosition > sender.value {
                    actuatorPosition = getActuatorPosition(label)
                }
                // stop opening
                self.writeValue(openCharacteristicNum, value: 1)
            }
            else if (actuatorPosition < sender.value) {
                // stop opening and start closing
                self.writeValue(openCharacteristicNum, value: 1)
                self.writeValue(closeCharacteristicNum, value: 0)
                while actuatorPosition < sender.value {
                    actuatorPosition = getActuatorPosition(label)
                }
                // stop closing
                self.writeValue(closeCharacteristicNum, value: 1)
            }
        }

    }
```

This feels like a very inefficient way to solve the problem (I'm not a fan of blocking threads with while loops) but I'm having trouble coming up with a better way.

Comment: The device is rather 'dumb'. It can accept a directional command but not a command to move to an absolute position, so it doesn't actually know when it has reached it's destination. I've edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a timer to regularly monitor the position of the device, which was much better than using while-loops.